# Synchronized Class in Java (i.e. Monitor)

Tags: java, synchronization

Is there any concept as synchronized CLASS in java which works same as Monitor ? I don't mean synchronized methods ! What I know about Monitor class is that when a thread is running any methods of an instance of this class , no other thread may have access to any method of this object

Comment: lets assume there is such concept. What do you need it for ?

Comment: To have that behavior, make all the methods of the class synchronized.

Comment: 1.Curiosity 2.Simplicity in some cases

Comment: What about making the class immutable? i.e. you cannot change its state, such as `java.lang.String`.

Comment: I am not familiar with this concept , but if you mean making an object unchangeable after its creation , it's not the same ! correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of is to make every method `synchronized`. There's no shortcut that would achieve this automatically for the entire class.

Comment: I guess that it doesn't result in the same behavior , 
let's assume that this class has two methods M1 & M2 , when M1 is executed by Thread1 no other thread (e.g. Thread2) may execute this method , but they may call another method M2 , right ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: No, wrong. No other thread can execute **any** synchronized method on the same instance.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh each instance has exactly one lock.